# Is it possible to make ifelse more things at once, as in if?

Tags: r, if-statement

I've been trying to sort of write a kernel regression on my own as practice.  If I understood the concept correctly, basically I need to sort of divide my data into some segments, and plot the mean of x any y in each segment and draw a line between them. I managed to write a code:

```
kernel = function(data){
  sor = length(unlist(data[1]))
  for (i in sor) {
    if( data[1]  <  blokk[1]){
      Blokk_1 = subset(data, data[1] < blokk[1])
      x_kor = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_1[1])))
      y_kor = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_1[2])))
      points(x_kor, y_kor, pch = 16, cex = 1.5, col = 2)
    } else if ( data[1] >=  blokk[1] & data[1] < blokk[2]){
      Blokk_2 = subset(data, data[1] >= blokk[1] & data[1] < blokk[2])
      x_kor2 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_2[1])))
      y_kor2 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_2[2])))
      points(x_kor2, y_kor2, pch = 16, cex = 1.5, col = 2)
    } else if (data[1] >= blokk[2] & data[1] < blokk[3]){
      Blokk_3 = subset(data, data[1] >= blokk[2] & data[1] < blokk[3])
      x_kor3 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_3[1])))
      y_kor3 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_3[2])))
      points(x_kor3, y_kor3, pch = 16, cex = 1.5, col = 2)
    } else if (data[1] > blokk[3]){
      Blokk_4 = subset(data, data[1] > blokk[3])
      x_kor4 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_4[1])))
      y_kor4 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_4[2])))
      points(x_kor4, y_kor4, pch = 16, cex = 1.5, col = 2)
    }
  }
}
```

I got a warning message about length (By the way: For some reason in the third block it managed to plot out the point). Googled it, apparently can't use vectors in if function. In another post I saw ifelse as suggestion, tried it aswell.

```
ifelse(data[1]  <  blokk[1],
       Blokk_1 = subset(data, data[1] < 19)
       x_kor = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_1[1])))
       y_kor = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_1[2])))
       points(x_kor, y_kor, pch = 16, cex = 1.5, col = 2),
       ifelse(data[1] >=  blokk[1] & data[1] < blokk[2],
         Blokk_2 = subset(data, data[1] >= blokk[1] & data[1] < blokk[2])
         x_kor2 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_2[1])))
         y_kor2 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_2[2])))
         points(x_kor2, y_kor2, pch = 16, cex = 1.5, col = 2),
         ifelse(data[1] >= blokk[2] & data[1] < blokk[3],
           Blokk_3 = subset(data, data[1] >= blokk[2] & data[1] < blokk[3])
           x_kor3 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_3[1])))
           y_kor3 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_3[2])))
           points(x_kor3, y_kor3, pch = 16, cex = 1.5, col = 2),
           ifelse(data[1] > blokk[3])
             Blokk_4 = subset(data, data[1] > blokk[3]),
             x_kor4 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_4[1])))
             y_kor4 = mean(as.numeric(unlist(Blokk_4[2])))
             points(x_kor4, y_kor4, pch = 16, cex = 1.5, col = 2)))))
```

It is not in a function yet, the nested ifelse I wrote, does not work, but when wrote separately, I worked. I don't know, if I made some error, when nesting it, or if I can't put this many output into one 'TRUE' section of ifelse.
Thank you in advance if you made it this far.

Edit: Since you asked for the reproducibility, here is the whole data (Note: it was a task within an exam, for linear regression)

```
 conc = c(19.2, 19.37, 19.23, 19.21, 19.58, 18.94, 19.46, 18.96, 19.26, 18.96, 19.02, 18.90, 19.14, 19.54, 18.96, 18.84, 18.82, 19.45,
 19.59, 19.54, 18.93, 19.51, 19.31, 19.30, 19.05, 18.84, 19.44, 18.82, 19.33, 19.37, 19.00, 19.32, 19.00, 19.27)
effect = c(67.97, 67.72, 67.64, 67.99, 68.32, 67.12, 68.70, 66.92, 67.55, 66.89, 67.00, 66.87, 67.46, 68.45, 66.92, 66.80, 66.96, 67.81,
68.92, 68.57, 67.43, 68.42, 67.87, 67.87, 67.09, 66.83, 68.50, 66.85, 67.78, 67.69, 66.95, 67.49, 67.52, 68.19)

df = data.frame(conc=conc, effect=effect)

blokk = seq(19, 19.4 , 0.2)
```

Edit 2.0: You were right, the problem is definitely with the 'for', running the if-s separately did the job. Still trying to find out how to solve the 'for'.

Comment: You have a *ton* of duplicate logic in your code. You can extract all that and shorten your code by ~80%. — Also, what do you mean by “I got a warning message about length”?

Comment: I meant this specifically: Warning messages:
1: In if (data[1] < blokk[1]) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (data[1] >= blokk[1] & data[1] < blokk[2]) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (data[1] >= blokk[2] & data[1] < blokk[3]) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: `length(unlist(data[1]))` looks dodgy. Also, you are iterating via `i in sor` but you are never using `i`.

Comment: Though, it only appears when I test the function

Comment: Just learning yet, Im as much of a newbie as I can be, can't you basically write anything in for instead of i ? Or only in python? (watched a python tutorial not long ago)

Comment: You can, but it usually doesn’t make sense: why are you iterating if you are not using the variable that you are iterating over? This is almost certainly related to the warning you are getting.

Comment: You can use `for(i in ...)` or `for(x in ....)` or `for(purple_strawberry in ...)`, but no matter what name you use for your iterator, if you don't use the iterator inside the loop, it's suspicious... nothing changes at each iteration so why bother iterating?

Comment: I think this question would be much clearer if you made it reproducible. Post a few rows of sample input, describe the goal, show the desired outcome.